# assign role to username and password using MVC 5

Tags: model-view-controller

Starting from the default MVC project with the login pages, how can I assign the role of users? In other words, if I want to create users and assign roles to each user how could that happen? I should be using identity 2.1.0 but don't know how anyone to guide me please I'm very new to MVC

Comment: That would be the same, but you can't let user's to select roles when they are registering , am I correct? What is your requirement? Explain it more?

Comment: plz read my comment in the previousquestion

Comment: better approach: the superuser is authorized to create an admin so need email password and role, the admin log in withthe email,password and role credentials if role=admin he is redirected to a page says hello admin.as for the user, he is allowed to register but without role ofcourse, when the user log in if the credentials are without role that is role=null, then he is redirected to a page hello user(no role for user).is it ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your previous comment

the superuser is authorized to create admins only,so the superuser create the role as well but only admin roles.and the admin after login, he is authorized to create users as well.so the superuser is allowed to create admins, and admins are allowed to create users.no user can create credentials for himself unless enduser. so the select role is specific for each create.is that clear enough?

In this case

```
superuser >> create admins. 
Admin >> create normal users
```

If I got you correct, you have separate create user views for create admin user (creating by SuperUser) and create normal user (creating by admin user). I think you don't need to have dropdownlist with roles as each create user (same as register user) view has particular single responsibility.

What you need to do is, handle assigning role part inside the create user (register user) action methods. I believe you have separate action methods for create admin user and create normal user. I will add some code sample if I got time later today.

You only need to use dropdownlist with populated roles if you are using same create user (register user) view (UI) for all type of user creations.

**Updated for comments*

I have added sample application on [gitHub](https://github.com/TechWhizIn/asp.net-Identity-framework-rolemanager-sample) with very basic login register with three roles to support your requirements.

Comment: right.can you help me on github project you uploaded to achieve the above comment?I will be most appreciated

Comment: Sorry, can't do now, will try to add some code later today.

Comment: Updated github project https://github.com/TechWhizIn/asp.net-Identity-framework-rolemanager-sample